# Total reputation is different in chat and flair

Tags: support, chat, flair, total-reputation

My total reputation is displayed on the [flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/ec1cd87bc2de4db7b4befff0fcb8e35e.png) as **31K**:

[image]

On my [Chat.SE profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/4456/kobi) it is displayed as **32.5K**:
[image]

There's a difference of about 1500 points - where are they?

- I've refreshed the flair image to make sure it isn't cached.
- I've considered a rep recalc, but there's only a difference of 139 points on meta and 134 points on SO (and not much activity on other sites).
- I did not have any recent significant reputation changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chat reputation is the sum of all of your accounts, regardless of reputation. Lots of associated accounts can boost it a lot.

Flair reputation, as mentioned on the flair page, only shows reputation for sites where you have at least 200 reputation.

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but that comment refers to the icons, I didn't think they wouldn't be summed.

Comment: @Kobi I did the math on my own accounts. I have 26k shown on my flair, and 26094 rep for the sum of >200 accounts. I have 26819 for chat, and the same if I sum everything.

Comment: Makes sense, but is that intended? I have 161 reputation on Math.SE - I want them counted! `:)`

Comment: @Kobi, while it is true that the flair data is cached for 24 hours, in your instance GraceNote is correct.  The sum of your accounts under 200 rep is approximately 1600.

Comment: @Rebecca - I see that. Is that by design? I thought it only affected the icons... Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Kobi, it says so on the flair page:  *(please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear.)* and it seems logical that if a site wouldn't appear, its rep would not be included.

Comment: @Kobi re: 161 on Math.SE: **answer more questions!!!** `;-)`

Comment: @Rebecca - Well, honestly, not really. It seems logical to sum everything and choose what to display, but it does answer the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Flair is cached for 24 hours on the server.

Your chat profile is refreshed hourly (I'm pretty sure it is hourly, but not certain...)

Comment: I didn't gain that much reputation yesterday - 0 point today, and 60 yesterday.