# chat reputation = sum of rep of all sites; flair rep = sum of rep on sites where rep > 200. Is this difference deliberate?

Tags: discussion, area-51, chat, flair

I notice that on chat, a user's reputation equals the sum of their reputations across all SE sites; whereas flair reputation equals the sum of reputations just for those SE sites where reputation is greater than 200. Is this difference in calculating rep deliberate? And if so, why?

I note that until about a year ago, Area51 showed rep on all sites (as chat does now), whereas flair showed the sum of rep only on sites where rep>200. After [a discussion here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65695/164022), Area51 was changed so that it conformed with flair. Can the same happen with chat?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the case now. Chat, Area51 and Flair reputation are all synced.

Comment: A related question: [Total reputation is different in chat and flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77716).